Flutter web window.open(url, '_self') clearing cache and cookies
is there any way to clear the cache and cookies after logging in? so if the user logs out of the app and logs back in, it won't automatically log in. I have a successful code in native mobile using webview_flutter package but it won't work in Web. Here is my sample code that working in native mobile:
                                    key: _key,
                                    backgroundColor: progressEnded != 100
                                        ? const Color(0xFF003D7F)
                                        : Colors.transparent,
                                    initialUrl: url,
                                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                                    navigationDelegate:
                                        (NavigationRequest request) async {
                                      Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.url);

                                      if (uri.queryParameters
                                          .containsKey('refreshToken')) {
                                        if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
                                          await launchUrl(uri).then((_) {
                                            if (!context.mounted) return;
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          });
                                        } else {
                                          debugPrint(' could not launch $uri');
                                        }

                                        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                                      }
                                      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                                    },
                                    onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                                      webViewController.clearCache();
                                      final cookieManager = CookieManager();
                                      cookieManager.clearCookies();
                                    },
                                    gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
                                    onProgress: (int progress) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        progressEnded = progress;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  )

